# Adding new XYZ tile connection using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, import, xyz-tiles, qgis-browser

How can I add a XYZ tiles connection to the list of stored connections using the PyQGIS without using `QGIS3.ini`/`QgsSettings`?

For example for the URL pattern `https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`

Comment: raw script https://raw.githubusercontent.com/klakar/QGIS_resources/master/collections/Geosupportsystem/python/qgis_basemaps.py (credit to Klas Karlsson).

Comment: "without using QGIS3.ini/QgsSettings" obviously includes the old `QSettings` approach.